# Hosting on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, hosting

I already have a domain name purchase from Google Domains.

I would like to host this site on Microsoft Azure, How should I plan to purchase all the required resources on Azure, if I want to host a Wordpress site, but would also need control over the size, if in future I plan to host some microsite with NodeJS or any other technologies like Java or .Net Core.

What would be my cost per month considering the above requirements?

Below is the list that I envisioned that I may need, can anyone suggest something this I missed.

1. A VM with Ubuntu (That would take care of Wordpress, Database(MySQL), NodeJS, Java and others)
2. Map my domain with Azure and map it with the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you're thinking of is also known as IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) and it is something you'd usually consider when migrating from an on-prem solution where you already have the VMs images for your needs.

In your particular case I'd recommend looking into PaaS (Platform as a Service) - specifically [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/app-service/).

Everything you enumerated can be hosted in an Azure App Service as it supports all major technologies for deploying web apps today (.Net, Node.js, Java, etc).

In addition to your own code, Azure offers a number of build-in templates for 3rd party vendors that allow you to deploy pre-packaged solutions such as Wordpress without having to worry about the installation yourself. See this [Wordpress on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/wordpress-app-service-mysql-inapp/) article for more details.

Pricing information for Azure Web Apps can be found on the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) page. In your case I suspect you could do with a B1 or S1 instance.

Lastly, for your domain name, you can easily map and configure any custom domain to an Azure Web App by simply updating the DNS records in your Domain Management system and reference that in the Azure Portal. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Alex's response. To provide you a good understanding on hosting website on Azure. Firstly, I wish to highlight that Azure offers several ways to host websites: Azure App Service WebApps (PAAS solution), Virtual Machines (IAAS), Service Fabric, and Cloud Services.

Azure App Service (PAAS solution) is the best choice for most web apps. Deployment and management are integrated into the platform, sites can scale quickly to handle high traffic loads, and the built-in load balancing and traffic manager provide high availability. 
WebApp is a fully managed compute platform that is optimized for hosting websites and web applications.
If you wish to host your website/app on an Azure VM (IAAS solution), you would typically install, design and configure the app in a similar way as you would onprem. If you have an existing application that would require substantial modifications to run in App Service you could choose Virtual Machines in order to simplify migrating to the cloud.

Take a look at the supported and unsupported configuration on App Service Migrate - Migration checklist when moving to Azure App Service : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/migration-checklist-when-moving-to-azure-app-service/